# Annotation Type Aggregator does not wrap return payload(DOMSource) with Message

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I have the following two methods(splitter and aggregator) that have been working fine on previous Spring Integration v4.x.

After migrating to Spring Integration v5, I got the following ClassCastException in aggregator only under a load test.

```
<bean id="airAvailabilitySplitter" class="c.s.s.integration.AvailabilitySplitter"/>
<bean id="airAvailabilityAggregator" class="c.s.s.integration.AvailabilityAggregator"/>
<int:channel id="airAvailRqChannel"/>
<int:channel id="airAvailAOGChannel"/>
<int:channel id="airAvailAggregatorChannel"/>
<int:chain id="sAirAvailabilityIDMToGdsProcess" input-channel="airAvailRqChannel" output-channel="airAvailAOGChannel">
    <int:header-enricher>
        <int:header name="originating-application-id" expression="#xpath(payload, '//*[local-name() = ''POS'']/@RequesterType=''ID'' ', 'boolean') ? '${myid.calling.app.identifier}' : '${calling.app.identifier}'"/>
        <int:header name="User-Agent" expression="@sRequestContext.shouldUseWiremockScenario() ? @sRequestContext.getWiremockScenario() : '${gds.header.useragent}'"/>
        <int:header name="gdsServiceName" value="Air_Availability"/>
    </int:header-enricher>
    <int-ws:header-enricher default-overwrite="true">
        <int-ws:soap-action expression="@wsapConfigMBean.gdsURL('http://webservices.gds.com/','/${gds.service.airextendedavailability}')"/>
    </int-ws:header-enricher>
    <int:splitter ref="airAvailabilitySplitter" method="split"/>
    <int-xml:validating-filter xml-validator="airExtendedAvailabilityXmlSchemaValidator" schema-type="xml-schema" throw-exception-on-rejection="true"/>
</int:chain>
```

```
<int:chain id="sAirAvailabilityAOGProcess" input-channel="airAvailAOGChannel" output-channel="airAvailAggregatorChannel">
    <!-- gds-outbound-gateway is extension of SimpleWebServiceOutboundGateway -->
    <sg:gds-outbound-gateway mapped-request-http-headers="User-Agent" gdsServiceName="Air_Availability" enclose="NO">
        <sg:request-handler-advice-chain>
            <bean class="org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.RequestHandlerRetryAdvice">
                <property name="retryTemplate">
                    <bean class="org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate">
                        <property name="retryPolicy">
                            <bean class="org.springframework.retry.policy.NeverRetryPolicy"/>
                        </property>
                    </bean>
                </property>
                <property name="recoveryCallback">
                    <bean class="c.s.r.ws.outbound.advice.OutboundGatewayErrorRecovery">
                        <property name="exitFlowAndReplyOnSystemException" value="true"/>
                    </bean>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </sg:request-handler-advice-chain>
    </sg:gds-outbound-gateway>
</int:chain>
<int:chain id="sAirAvailabilityAggregatorProcess" input-channel="airAvailAggregatorChannel" output-channel="airAvailabilityServiceLayerToIDMRouterChannel">
    <int:aggregator ref="airAvailabilityAggregator" method="aggregate"/>
</int:chain>
```

```
   @Splitter
   public List<DOMSource> split(DOMSource idm) {      
      try {
         List<DOMSource> gdsAirAvailabilityRequests = new ArrayList<DOMSource>();
         Transformer transformer = idmtogdsAirAvailabilityTemplate.newTransformer();
         int numOfOnDs = getNumOfOnDs(idm);
         for (int i = 1; i <= numOfOnDs; i++) { transformer.setParameter("originDestinationIndex", i); Result gdsAirAvailRqResult=new DOMResult(); transformer.transform(idm, gdsAirAvailRqResult); DOMSource gdsAirAvailRqDomSource=(DOMSource) resultTransformer.transformResult(gdsAirAvailRqResult); gdsAirAvailabilityRequests.add(gdsAirAvailRqDomSource); } return gdsAirAvailabilityRequests; } catch (Exception e) { throw new ApplicationException(e.getMessage(), e); } }
            <!-- c.s.s.integration.AvailabilityAggregator -->
   @Aggregator
   public DOMSource aggregate(List<Message<DOMSource>> gdsResponses) {
      Document doc = docBuilder.newDocument();
      doc.appendChild(doc.createElement("Air_AvailabilityReplies"));
      for (Message<DOMSource> gdsResponse : gdsResponses) { <!-- This line throws ClassCastException -->
         doc.getFirstChild().appendChild(doc.importNode(gdsResponse.getPayload().getNode(), true));
      }
      DOMSource domSource = new DOMSource(doc);
      return domSource;
   }

<!-- Spring Integration Header values -->   
2021-04-21 15:37:28,277 DEBUG [tomcat-http--53] {trans-id=306acc27-e233-4fb8-8a31-648739967033} org.springframework.integration.aggregator.AggregatingMessageHandler - Handling message with correlationKey [43b51d74-101b-22b1-3d29-b781deccde5c]: GenericMessage [payload=javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource@1f30953, headers={sequenceDetails=[[306acc27-e233-4fb8-8a31-648739967033, 0, 0]], sequenceNumber=1, errorChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@59f4dca9, s-originating-application-id=s, sequenceSize=1, User-Agent=Web Service Client, gdsService=Air_Availability, replyChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@59f4dca9, gdsServiceVersion=12_1, gdsServiceName=Air_Availability, ws_soapAction=http://webservices.gds.com/XXXXXXXXXXX/ABC_12_1_1A, correlationId=43b51d74-101b-22b1-3d29-b781deccde5c, id=3addb1e6-289c-b2bc-f9ef-6871e699cce3, timestamp=XXXXXXXXX8277}]

  <!--StackTrace -->
    org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: error occurred in message handler [sAirAvailabilityAggregatorProcess$child#0.handler]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource cannot be cast to org.springframework.messaging.Message
            at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:153) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.integration.handler.MessageHandlerChain.handleMessageInternal(MessageHandlerChain.java:110) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:141) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:132) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:105) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:73) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:438) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:388) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:181) ~[spring-messaging-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:160) ~[spring-messaging-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47) ~[spring-messaging-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:108) ~[spring-messaging-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:418) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.produceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:328) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.integration.handler.MessageHandlerChain$ReplyForwardingMessageChannel.send(MessageHandlerChain.java:238) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.messaging.MessageChannel.send(MessageChannel.java:45) ~[spring-messaging-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:181) ~[spring-messaging-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:160) ~[spring-messaging-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47) ~[spring-messaging-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:108) ~[spring-messaging-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:418) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.produceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:328) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutputs(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:219) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:115) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:141) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.integration.handler.MessageHandlerChain.handleMessageInternal(MessageHandlerChain.java:110) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:141) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:132) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:105) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:73) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:438) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:388) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:181) ~[spring-messaging-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:160) ~[spring-messaging-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47) ~[spring-messaging-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:108) ~[spring-messaging-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:418) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.produceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:328) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.integration.handler.MessageHandlerChain$ReplyForwardingMessageChannel.send(MessageHandlerChain.java:238) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.messaging.MessageChannel.send(MessageChannel.java:45) ~[spring-messaging-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:181) ~[spring-messaging-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:160) ~[spring-messaging-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47) ~[spring-messaging-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:108) ~[spring-messaging-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
```

We ran out room to post the complete stack trace.   Let us know if the full stack trace is needed.

Comment: `spsAirAvailabilityAggregatorProcess$child#0.handler` - sounds like you have somewhere in your config a `<chain>` definition. Would be great if you can share with us a simple project to let us to reproduce. I mean that info you provide right now in the question is not enough to chase the problem. Thanks for understanding!

Comment: Have just tested it in a simple unit-test - works well. Probably the problem is not about an aggregator. Need more context from your. Or let's just see more stack trace from the error to be sure which Spring Integration component suffers that error.

Comment: Hello Artem.   Thank you for looking into this issue.   Example of the config and the codes are below.   This error only occurs under heavy load, e.g. 15 concurrent transaction or more.

Comment: Sorry, this code is not readable in the comments. Please, consider to edit your question with that info. Plus include the logic of your `AvailabilitySplitter` and `AvailabilityAggregator`. As long as they are your own code, we can't guess what is going on with your application.

Comment: I am having an issue for adding a large sample codes in the comment.

Comment: Yeah... Not clear what is going on then. It would be great if you can come up with something pretty straightforward to share with us via GitHub, so we can run on our side and reproduce. Well, share, please, at least the whole stack trace, so we would have more context to investigate.

Comment: I updated the content of the problem.   Could not post the whole stack trace.   Hope there is enough info there.